# Accessing a single model between multiple apps - Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a Django project with two app that are users and groups. I have a model named Friend in the users app. I want to access the model in the groups app. How can I import the Friend model from the users app within the groups app. I want to access the other models to make queries and querysets in the groups app from the models in the groups app.

Here are the import statements I have right now...

Imports for the views in the users app:

```
from .forms import *
from .method import *
from .models import *
```

Imports for the veiws in the groups app:

```
from .forms import *
from .models import *
```

How can i import the users models in the groups app. I also want to import the groups models in the users models.

Here is the current directory....

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [app].models import [model]

```
from user.models import  Class
```

Or

```
from groups.models import Class
```

Be sure you have created  __init__.py files on every app directory

Comment: So if i want to import all the models I can use something like this for example: `from groups.models import *` and that would work... @mtt2p

Comment: also all the apps have an `__init__.py` file when they are created so I dont have to really worry about that... right? @mtt2p

Comment: It worked thanks... all of the stack overflow question about this are way more complicated than the simple answer you put... thanks again... lol